# Convert For into ForEach loop in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary, swiftui

I am having issues converting

```
for(key, value) in Array(self.categoriesList.subCategoryList).sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0}){

}
```

to

```
ForEach(){response in

}
```

The reason is the first for loop isn't allowed in a 'ViewBuilder' for 'SwiftUI' so I've tried this but still have no luck. Any guidance for going about it? So far I've tried this but I get an error code

> referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that '[Int : [Int : String]]' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'

The Dictionary i'm trying to for loop is this.

```
self.categoriesList.subCategoryList = Dictionary<Int,Dictionary<Int,String>>()

ForEach (self.categoriesList.subCategoryList, id: \.self){subCategory in

}
```

Comment: That's not how we present code here.

Comment: What is it you want to show from the dictionary, the values (inner dictionaries) or the whole dictionary? Also, if this dictionary comes from json data then it might be better to use Codable

Comment: Depending on your answer to the above question, you may be able to do this: `ForEach (self.categoriesList.subCategoryList.map { ($0, $1) }, id: \.1){ (key, value) in`

Comment: @jnpdx You nailed it! Worked like a charm. I took this approach for a nested for loop as well. Thank you so much! How can I approve your answer as the solution to my question?

Comment: @JuanColmenero I've added it as an actual answer. You can use the green checkmark to mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get `key` `value` pairs in your `ForEach`, you could do something like this:

```
ForEach (self.categoriesList.subCategoryList.map { ($0, $1) }, id: \.1){ (key, value) in
```

It uses `map` on the original `Dictionary` to split it into the key/value pairs.

Comment: Since you mentioned in the comment thread that this solved your issue, you can mark it as correct with the green check mark.